# How can I copy an ostringstream object into another one (using gcc-4.7.0)

Tags: c++, gcc, ostringstream

All the other posts tell me to change my compiler, but I can't since I'm supposed to be working with this compiler. Please help!

```
void foo(ostringstream &os) {
    ostringstream temp;
    temp << 0;
    //do something
    os.swap(temp);
}
```

^I can' really upload the do-something part, since it's a part of a school project, but the compiler is giving me an error at: os.swap(temp);

I also tried the =operator and that didn't work as well

Comment: Hard to provide a solution without seeing exactly what you're trying to accomplish in your code. Please **edit** your post and include the _relevant_ portions of code there.

Comment: The simple solution in the sample you posted would be to use `os` directly instead of a second `temp` stream that later has to get copied to `os`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) member function in [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to both obtain the buffer from the temporary stream *and* set the buffer passed to `foo`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void foo(std::ostringstream &os)
{
    std::ostringstream temp;

    temp << "goodbye";

    //do something

    os.str(temp.str()); //  Set the new buffer contents
}


int main()
{
    std::ostringstream out;

    out << "hello";
    std::cout << out.str() << std::endl;
    foo(out);
    std::cout << out.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively you can eliminate the use of a temporary stream by clearing the buffer in `os` as soon as you enter `foo` and output directly to `os`. Your post doesn't provide enough information to determine if this will be useful to you but it's an option.

```
void foo(std::ostringstream &os)
{
    os.str(""); //  Set the new buffer contents

    os << "goodbye";

    // do something
}
```